# how to add scrollbar to table in php?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I was wondering how I could add a scroll to my table that is written in the php file. I do not want to write it in a style.css file, I want it directly in the php file. below is my code, but I am not able to make it to work. The table gets content from mySql database, which works. but the problem is that I get to much of content so it fills out the whole page. That is why I want to make it scrollable :

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
   echo '<table border="1">';
               echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<th>Name</th>";
               echo "</tr>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
           }
           echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If the page exceeds the browser window size, the browser will automatically add scrollbars.  What exactly is the problem?  Do you have CSS which is preventing that automatic behavior?  Are you trying to do something else?  Also, PHP has *nothing* to do with your client-side styling.  That's entirely the HTML and CSS.  Whether you want it to be or not.

Comment: you can only add scroll with css.you can add inline styling for that

Comment: @David the page exceeds the browser, but it does not add the scroll. I do now have any css at all

Comment: @Sikandar_ali I did try adding echo "<table  <style>  overflow-y: scroll; </style>>"; but it did not work

Comment: @jacub: Then you have an invalid assumption somewhere.  Scrollbars are *default behavior* when page content exceeds the window size.  Something else must be preventing that.  Perhaps it's CSS, perhaps it's a browser setting, etc.  But somewhere you are, intentionally or otherwise, preventing default behavior.  Whatever is doing that, that's where the problem is.

Comment: @jacub this is not the way to add inline style "<table <style> overflow-y: scroll; </style>>" you can add inline style by adding style attribute like this "<table style="overflow-y:scroll;">".

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL, and entirely to do with HTML and CSS.

Comment: @David the whole page does scroll when the table exceeds the page, but I do not want it to do that. I want it to just be a small area, and then you can scroll to see the rest of the content

Comment: @Sikandar_ali tried to do that, but it does not work..

Answer (score 1):

If im getting your question right you need to set a width and height then set  the overflow-y.  This will give you a table set to a certain size with a scroll bar. Note you need to set your own width and height.

```
echo "<table style=\"width:500px; height:500px; overflow-y:auto\">";
```